# How do I iterate over a list of strings and identify ints and floats and then add them to a list?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to iterate over list of strings to add both floats and ints to another list. My code below works for ints, but not for floats and I don't know why.

My pseudo code would be: for element in list, if element is float or int, add to list.

So in the code below I use these two inputs, but you will see the issues. How can I fix this?

```
theInput1 = "3.2+.4*5.67/6.145="
theInput2 = "11.897/3.4+9.2-0.4*6.9/12.6-16.7="
```

And here is my code below when I use the first input:

```
import re
a = "3.2+.4*5.67/6.145="
a2 = [x for x in re.split("(\d*\.?\d*)", a) if x != '']

s = []

for i in a2:
  if i >='0' and i <='9':
    s.append(i)

print(s)
```

This is the output that I get:

```
['3.2', '5.67', '6.145']
```

I'm not sure what happened to the 0.4?

The result for the second input:

```
['11.897', '3.4', '0.4', '6.9', '12.6', '16.7']
```

Again the 9.2 is missing...

For this input without floats it works fine:

```
"(12+3)*(56/2)/(34-4)="
```

I get this output which works:

```
['12', '3', '56', '2', '34', '4']
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) instead of split:

```py
import re


def get_numbers(s):
    floats = []
    ints = []
    for x in re.findall(r"\d*\.?\d+", s):
        if '.' in x:
            floats.append(float(x))
        else:
            ints.append(int(x))
    return floats, ints


# For Display
print('Floats', get_numbers("11.897/3.4+9.2-0.4*6.9/12.6-16.7="))  # Floats Only
print('Ints  ', get_numbers("(12+3)*(56/2)/(34-4)="))  # Ints Only
print('Mixed ', get_numbers("(12+.3)*(56.36/2.15)/(34-4)="))  # Mixed
```

Output:

```
Floats ([11.897, 3.4, 9.2, 0.4, 6.9, 12.6, 16.7], [])
Ints   ([], [12, 3, 56, 2, 34, 4])
Mixed  ([0.3, 56.36, 2.15], [12, 34, 4])
```

---

The individual lists can be accessed like so:

```
f, i = get_numbers("(12+.3)*(56.36/2.15)/(34-4)=")
```

Comment: What if I want it to append floats OR ints, so that it works in both input cases?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. If you run this with `a` as `"(12+3)*(56/2)/(34-4)="` you'll get `[12.0, 3.0, 56.0, 2.0, 34.0, 4.0]`. You can always change `float` to `int` to change the conversion type. Or are you asking how to selectively determine if something is a float or an int, and cast them to the correct type? Or Did you want ints and floats in separate lists?

Comment: As I iterate through the string I'm trying to push floats and ints onto a stack actually. So, I want it to be able to recognize floats or ints. I'm not trying to convert between the two.

Comment: Does something like the current edit work?

Comment: No because a simple if/else wont work. This is part of a bigger if function. When I encounter a float or an int, I am trying to push those items to a stack. When I encounter an operator "+-/*" or brackets "()" I have if statements that do other things. I tried to use the isinstance() function, but I'm not having luck with it.

Comment: You probably need to open another SO question, because it sounds like you're trying to do a "stack based expression evaluator" type problem. However, the question you've asked is how do I "identify ints and floats and add them to a list" which will have very different answers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in comparison `i <= "9"`. Obviously `"9.2"` fails the check so it isn't added to the list.

You can try:

```
import re

a = "11.897/3.4+9.2-0.4*6.9/12.6-16.7="
a2 = [x for x in re.split(r"(\d*\.?\d*)", a) if x != ""]
s = []

for i in a2:
    try:
        s.append(float(i))
    except ValueError:
        continue

print(s)
```

Prints:

```
[11.897, 3.4, 9.2, 0.4, 6.9, 12.6, 16.7]
```

Comment: What if I want it to append floats OR ints? I tried it on the ints input and it turns ints to floats.